# Cache a model and extend another to lookup values with it

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in the controllers:

```
.factory('TaskLinks', function($resource) {
  var task_links = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/task_links', {},
    {query:
      {
        cache: true,
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  return task_links;
})

.factory('Timesheets', function($resource, TaskLinks) {
  var Timesheet = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/timesheets');
  angular.extend(Timesheet.prototype, {
    project: function() {
      return TaskLinks[this.task_id].project_name
    }
  });
  return Timesheet;
})
```

My goal is to cache all the task links and to extend the timesheet so I can do this {{ timesheet.project() }} in my template.  However it's not working.  It doesn't return anything for project.  I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'project' of undefined
```

And I don't see the call being made to the server (even when I try setting cache to false).  Maybe it has to do with a promise?
(I'm very new to Angular so take into account that there could be some serieus issues with this code :-)

EDIT: controller code:

```
.controller('TimesheetCtrl', function($scope, TimeDate) {
    $scope.$TimeDate = TimeDate;
  })
```

This calls TimeDate (it has functions to go to next and previous date and reload timesheet, which I now omitted):

```
.factory('TimeDate', function(Timesheets) {
  var currentDate = new Date();

  var timesheets = Timesheets.query({q: {time_start_gteq: currentDate, time_start_lt: moment(currentDate).add(1, 'd').toDate() }});

  return {
    currentDate: function() {
      return currentDate;
    },
    timesheets: function () {
      return timesheets
    }
  }
  })
```

Template is something like this:

```
        <ion-item ng-repeat="timesheet in $TimeDate.timesheets()">
            <h2>{{timesheet.project() }}</h2>
            <p>{{timesheet.notes}}</p>
            <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        </ion-item>
```

EDIT2:

I altered this part of the server and now when I debug I see the actual value being returned.  However: the query seems to be called an enormous amount of times and in the view there isn't anything being displayed as project id.

```
.factory('Timesheets', function($resource, $filter, TaskLinks) {
  var Timesheet = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/timesheets');
  angular.extend(Timesheet.prototype, {
    project: function() {
      var that = this;
      return $filter('filter')(TaskLinks.query().$promise, {id: that.task_link_id})[0].project_id;
      TaskLinks.query().$promise.then(function(response){
        var project = $filter('filter')(response, {id: that.task_link_id})[0].project_id;
        return project;
      });
    }
  });
  return Timesheet;
})
```

Comment: Could you share your controller code too?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that `$TimeDate.timesheets()` is a promise object, not the response for request, you need to handle it properly, smth like this:

```
.controller('TimesheetCtrl', function($scope, TimeDate) {
    TimeDate.timesheets().$promise.then(function(response){
        //response <- actual response from server
        $scope.timesheets = response;
    });
  })
```

html:

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="timesheet in timesheets">
      <h2>{{timesheet.project() }}</h2>
      <p>{{timesheet.notes}}</p>
      <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
  </ion-item>
```

but I would recommend to use `resolve` from `$routeProvider` to load data into controller, in this case all data wii be already in controller, so view will look better.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't make any difference.  The TaskLinks in the angular.extend(Timesheet.prototype part still stays undefined.